# App launch crash -- unable to load script

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio

I generated signed release universal apk for React Native `0.67.4` app and the release app installed on real device keeps crashing with the following error:

```
04-08 12:20:53.828  4299  4430 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: create_react_context
04-08 12:20:53.828  4299  4430 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.xyz_app6, PID: 4299
04-08 12:20:53.828  4299  4430 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load script. Make sure you're either running Metro (run 'npx react-native start') or that your bundle 'index.android.bundle' is packaged correctly for release.
04-08 12:20:53.828  4299  4430 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.jniLoadScriptFromAssets(Native Method)
04-08 12:20:53.828  4299  4430 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.loadScriptFromAssets(Unknown Source:2)
04-08 12:20:53.828  4299  4430 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.JSBundleLoader$1.loadScript(Unknown Source:10)
04-08 12:20:53.828  4299  4430 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.runJSBundle(Unknown Source:18)
04-08 12:20:53.828  4299  4430 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.o.s(Unknown Source:177)
04-08 12:20:53.828  4299  4430 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.o.d(Unknown Source:0)
04-08 12:20:53.828  4299  4430 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.o$f.run(Unknown Source:68)
04-08 12:20:53.828  4299  4430 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:929)
```

The android studio is 2021.1.1 patch 2 and here is the output of `./gradlew --version`:

```
% ./gradlew --version

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 7.4.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2022-03-09 15:04:47 UTC
Revision:     36dc52588e09b4b72f2010bc07599e0ee0434e2e

Kotlin:       1.5.31
Groovy:       3.0.9
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.11 compiled on July 10 2021
JVM:          11.0.12 (Eclipse Foundation 11.0.12+7)
OS:           Mac OS X 11.2 x86_64
```

The package was built with `/gradlew assembleRelease` following the [standard signing config](https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android) for React Native. `Hermes` enabled and `ProGuard` true in config. What is missing with the release package?

Comment: Issue disappeared after downgrading gradle plugin in build.gradle from 7.1.0 to 7.0.4